# Prawn: How to make “Leader dots” for Table of content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm using Prawn gem to generate PDF documents within my Rails Application. I've successfully created the PDFs But I have a table of contents and I wonder is it possible Or Is there is a way to create the leader dots effect in Prawn [image]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to create the leader dots effect in Praw.

If you have:

1. the total available width
2. width of the table of content entry
3. width of the page number
4. width of a single *leader dot*

`space_for_dots = 1. - 2. - 3.`

`dots = (space_for_dots / 4) * '.'`

`toc_entry = entry_string + dots + entry_page_number`

---

To calculate the width of a string in prawn, you can use [compute_width_of](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn%2FFont%2FTTF%3Acompute_width_of), which is part of the font classes.

An example for the picture you added could look like this:

```
def build_toc_entry(left_text, right_text, available_width, text_size)
  left_text_width = font(YOUR_FONT).compute_width_of(left_text, size: text_size)
  right_text_width = font(YOUR_FONT).compute_width_of(right_text, size: text_size)
  dot_width = font(YOUR_FONT).compute_width_of('.', size: text_size)
  space_width = font(YOUR_FONT).compute_width_of(' ', size: text_size)

  space_for_dots = available_width - left_text_width - right_text_width - space_width * 2
  dots = '.' * (space_for_dots / dot_width)

  "#{left_text} #{dots} #{right_text}" # return the finished toc entry
end

text 'Locate the information on the page indicated.'
text build_toc_entry('Leader Dots', '3', 350, 8)
text build_toc_entry('Dingbats', '5', 350, 8)
text build_toc_entry('Bullets', '8', 350, 8)
```

Comment: This seems like a good start, but the dots in leaders need to align vertically. I think that will require more logic.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean.
In the picture OP provided the leader dots start right after the ToC item and go all the way to right before the page number.
My example does just that, if you need every ToC line to have the same length, just use the same `available_width`.
Unless you are actually talking about every single dot being placed perfectly under/above another dot. I didn't specifically consider that, but I think the main problem with doing this effect is not knowing about `compute_width_of` and by using it you can make something like this kind of alignment also work.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Go look at most any table of contents. The dots of different entries align in vertical columns.  It's one of those typesetting conventions so common that they go unnoticed until violated. Here's an example: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html And if you look at the OP's image, you'll notice the dots are vertically aligned there, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late but here is what I did to get the dots to align properly with only left side text. But I think it would be reasonably easy to modify for left and right text:

```
def build_dots(text, available_width, text_size)
        dots_hash = {}
        current_font = font.inspect.split('<')[1].split(':')[0].strip
      text_width = font(current_font).compute_width_of(text, size: text_size)
      dot_width = font(current_font).compute_width_of('.', size: text_size)
      space_width = font(current_font).compute_width_of(' ', size: text_size)

      space_for_dots = available_width - text_width - space_width * 2
      dots = '.' * (space_for_dots / dot_width)
      dots_width = font(current_font).compute_width_of(dots, size: text_size)
      dots_start = available_width - dots_width - (space_width * 2)
      dots_hash[:dots] = dots
      dots_hash[:position] = dots_start

      return dots_hash
end

    dot_values = build_dots(officer.title,150,text_size)
    p = 0
    float {
        text "#{officer.title}", size: text_size
    }

    indent(dot_values[:position]) do
        float {
            text dot_values[:dots], size: text_size
        }
    end

    p += 150
    indent(p,0) do
        text "#{officer.name}", size: text_size
    end
```